# How to Disconnect from BT without Unpairing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

In Windows 10's default BT stack, it seems like there's no option to simply "disconnect" a BT device. It gives me the option to "remove" it, which does disconnect the device, but it also deletes the ID. I use a program with my BT device that automatically loads settings, but it looks for the ID to do so, so if I remove the device, I have to set it to load the proper settings again. There MUST be a way to disconnect from Bluetooth without removing the device entirely, no?

Comment: What happens if you simply turn Bluetooth off on your device?

Comment: When I do this, Windows thinks it's still paired, and when I try to connect again it doesn't let me. It doesn't show up when I try to search with Action Center either.